# Can I reduce the number of bits after Arithmetic Right Shift?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

If I reduce the number of bits after arithmetic right shift in verilog, do I still get the correct signed number? Is this valid?

number of bits reduced = shift value

```
A = 1110_1110
A>>>1
new A = 111_0111
```

Comment: well,  obviously it depends on the number of bits you want to  reduce and the meaning of the value after reduction. I.e., if you  reduce it by 1 bit, you will save the sign in the smaller-sized vector. But if you want to assign it back to the previous sized vector, you will get it zero-extended and it might be different from the original vector.  So, you need to provide more information.

Comment: Hi, the shifted value is assigned to a new variable instead of the previous size vector. So as long as the number of bits deducted is equal to the shift value, I guess that's fine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should use three '>' not four and of course the new variable should be big enough:

```
wire signed [7:0] A,B;
wire signed [6:0] just_fits;
wire signed [5:0] oops;

  assign         B = A >>> 1;  // Signed divide by two
  assign just_fits = A >>> 1;  // Signed divide by two
  assign      oops = A >>> 1;  // Goes wrong
```